# Computer does not progress past initial loading screen

Tags: boot, bios, toshiba-laptop

My Toshiba P300 laptop turns on okay and the large Toshiba logo appears. Usually around a second later the message saying something like

> Press F2 to enter setup or F12 for boot options

However this isn't appearing and the laptop doesn't proceed past this point.

I would assume it is having problems reading the BIOS.  Would this assumption be right?  If so could someone tell me how I could resolve it?

In a PC I would try removing the CMOS battery, but in a laptop I think they're different.

Comment: Your BIOS could be corrupted. Have you try to update it recently?

Comment: Well, I think you should look for the CMOS battery first. If the CMOS battery is obscured I would suggest a hard reset of the BIOS.

Comment: After taking the laptop to pieces I found out it had a lithium ion battery embedded in the motherboard and have given up!